# Oauth.io incremental authorization

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, gmail-api

### Using the [Oauth.io  JS SDK](https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/javascript), how can I pass additional arguments in my initial request?

I've tried passing an `options` object to the `Oauth.popup()` function, but that is not working.

I would like to be able to include additional scopes in the initial request or at least an `include_granted_scopes` options so I can request more scopes later.

*The ultimate goal is to access a user's Gmail inbox via the* [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview#auth_and_the_gmail_api) *at* https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

For some reason I can not include this scope on the Oauth.io project dashboard.

Also, I have to use keep using Oauth.io popups for now because I do not have a static redirect uri to receive the response as I am testing with localhost. Otherwise I realize that could just handle all this manually.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem using the exact same scope to access the Gmail API. I got it working using the 'https://mail.google.com/' and 'email' scopes on the Google Mail provider.

[image: These are the scopes you need]

That will let you make authorized HTTPS requests to the Gmail API functions like so:

```
OAuth.popup('google_mail', {cache: true})
    .done(function(result) {
        result.me().done(function(data) {
            result.get("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=INBOX")
            .done(function(list) {
            etc...
```

Just check the Gmail API functions for the appropriate HTTPS requests for whatever method you want to call.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The [scope docs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) don't really seem to suggest that this will work, but it does.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bunch of playtesting until we found a configuration that worked.